# Rails Postgres should I add foreign key indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

If I have the following line in a migration, will postgresql add an implicit index? Should I explicitly add an index for the foreign key? The models contain has_many and belongs_to as appropriate.

```
t.integer :club_id,
          :null => false,
          :options => "CONSTRAINT fk_transactions_club REFERENCES clubs(id)"
```

Comment: Aren't FKeys declared automatically when using `has_many`/`belongs_to`?

Comment: @Denis: Nope, Rails doesn't believe in fancy stuff like database FKs.

Comment: @muistooshort: ouch... things like this make me so glad I decided to not waste time on that thing when I learned Ruby.

Comment: You're wondering about indexing `club_id`, correct? The referenced column for an FK is always uniquely constrained (possibly via a PK) so it will be indexed already.

Comment: @Denis my concern is that you'd criticise the framework for not magically applying FKs and not take your database design more seriously and *expect* to apply them yourself. Rails, though opinionated, is not a dictatorship.

Comment: @Damien: Being an SQL person, I preferred Sequel's approach for ORMs. This was admittedly before Rails3 and Arel, but I stuck with the decision regardless: Rails features uncomfortably high amounts of magic that make its internals difficult to grasp without hours upon hours of study. It's a matter of taste, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

> **5.3.5. Foreign Keys**
>   [...]
>   Since a `DELETE` of a row from the referenced table or an `UPDATE` of a referenced column will require a scan of the referencing table for rows matching the old value, it is often a good idea to index the referencing columns. Because this is not always needed, and there are many choices available on how to index, declaration of a foreign key constraint does not automatically create an index on the referencing columns.

You're FK is referencing a PK so you probably don't have to worry about UPDATEs. If your referencing table (the one with `club_id`) is going to be large and you're expecting to be deleting `club` rows often, then an index of some sort on `club_id` should make deleting `club` rows faster. If you don't have an index on `club_id`, attempting to delete a `club` row will require a table scan on the table containing `club_id` and table scans are not your friend.

So the answer is *maybe, it depends on how `club` will be used*.

Comment: The parent record will rarely be deleted and then only by me so time is not an issue. I am more concerned about lots of selects from child tables using where(:club_id = session[:club_id]) and inserting new child records.

Comment: If you're going to be querying on `club_id` a lot then, yeah, an index is a good idea independent of any FK issues. I thought you were only interested in the FK aspect.